# How to define variable for Output path in Wix?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I would like to define a variable somewhere that I can use in Output path of a WiX project within Visual Studio. By default, Output path is `bin\$(Configuration)\`. However, I would like to have something like `bin\$(Configuration)\$(Version)`. I've tried to define it in `Define Variables` field without success.

Comment: Where does the value of Version come from because that might significantly shape the solution. (I've done some automation where it is extracted from one of the content files. On the other hand, perhaps you want it from the Product/@Version attribute.)

Comment: It comes from user to Define Preprocessor Field, as `Version=1.6`. Then this variable is used inside `.wxs` file inside same Setup Project. My option now is to define the same version once in Preprocessor Field, then into Output Path field. To avoid this I thought it's possible to specify it in once place only. I know there is some black magic which can let me modify anything in project file, but I would rather avoid it.